# button_tag not send commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for

I need use `button_tag` instead `submit_tag` on a form to add icon with style http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons.

```
<%= simple_form_for(bla..........bla......)) do  %>
 <%= button_tag t('.sent_to_trash'), :class => "btn btn-small btn-primary disabled", :id => "trash_button", do %>
   <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
   <%= t('.sent_to_trash') %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**The question is I can not receive the `params[:commit]` with `button_tag`, however with `submit_tag` is working fine and I receive correctly `params[:commit]` on my action controller.**

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html element `button` works with `:name` and `:value` params, so you have to explicitly define these, e.g.

```
= button_tag(:name => "commit", :value => "my_button") do
  = "Press me!"
```

then you get `params[:commit] = "my_button"` after form submit.

**Note:** You should specify `:type` attribute too, because different browsers use different default types for the `<button>` element (`:type => "submit"`)